# Cannot find a version of 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads' that satisfies the version constraints:

Tags: android, react-native, admob

I am getting error above . In my build.gradle dependencies i have added

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.1.0'`

Complete error below . Any Suggestions ? FYI I am using react-native

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.1.0.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads' that satisfies the version constraints:
> Dependency path 'halkee:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.1.0'
> Constraint path 'halkee:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:{strictly 22.0.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 22.0.0`

I have tried changing the version in dependecy to 22.0.0 and and got error below

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID@value value=(ca-app-pub-5953875387948501~2537651271) from AndroidManifest.xml:18:13-67
> is also present at [:react-native-google-mobile-ads] AndroidManifest.xml:16:13-67 value=(ca-app-pub-5953875387948501~3589479695).
> Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:16:6-18:69 to override.

Comment: The error message indicates that there is a version conflict with the com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads dependency in your Android project.  Check your play-services-ads version and change it to match the constraint

Comment: @Vinay where do i check to see they match exaclty ? i can only see version 22.1.0 in my build.gradle file but i do not see 22.0.0 anywhere

Comment: Are you using any other google play service with different version?

Comment: im using 22.1.0 from google play services sdk , however on my gradle depencies it says 22.0.0 . Is there anyway i can change the gradle depency to 22.1.0 . I have tried edditing build.gradle which doesnt do anything